# Implementation of the SHA256 algorithm do not return the expected result

Tags: c++, sha256

With the implementation below, based on the pseudo-code available [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2), I am trying to convert a string generated with the concatenation of the members from this class:

```
class BlockHeader
{
private:
  int version;
  string hashPrevBlock;
  string hashMerkleRoot;
  int time;
  int bits;
  int nonce;
}
```

into a SHA256 hash, like what was done with the python code below, available [here](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Block_hashing_algorithm):

```
>>> import hashlib
>>> header_hex = ("01000000" +
 "81cd02ab7e569e8bcd9317e2fe99f2de44d49ab2b8851ba4a308000000000000" +
 "e320b6c2fffc8d750423db8b1eb942ae710e951ed797f7affc8892b0f1fc122b" +
 "c7f5d74d" +
 "f2b9441a" +
 "42a14695")
>>> header_bin = header_hex.decode('hex')
>>> hash = hashlib.sha256(hashlib.sha256(header_bin).digest()).digest()
>>> hash.encode('hex_codec')
'1dbd981fe6985776b644b173a4d0385ddc1aa2a829688d1e0000000000000000'
>>> hash[::-1].encode('hex_codec')
'00000000000000001e8d6829a8a21adc5d38d0a473b144b6765798e61f98bd1d'
```

I expect that my program would return the same result the program above returned, but instead, when I compile and run this:

```
int main() {
  BlockHeader header;
  header.setVersion(0x01000000);
  header.setHashPrevBlock("81cd02ab7e569e8bcd9317e2fe99f2de44d49ab2b8851ba4a308000000000000");
  header.setHashMerkleRoot("e320b6c2fffc8d750423db8b1eb942ae710e951ed797f7affc8892b0f1fc122b");
  header.setTime(0xc7f5d74d);
  header.setBits(0xf2b9441a);
  header.setNonce(0x42a14695);

  Sha256 hash1(header.bytes());
  array<BYTE, SHA256_BLOCK_SIZE> h1 = hash1.hash();

  cout << "hash1: ";
  for(int i=0; i<h1.size(); i++)
    printf("%.2x", h1[i]);
  printf("\n");

  Sha256 hash2(h1);
  array<BYTE, SHA256_BLOCK_SIZE> h2 = hash2.hash();

  cout << "hash2: ";
  for(int i=0; i<h2.size(); i++)
    printf("%.2x", h2[i]);
  printf("\n");
}
```

the result is that:

```
hash1: e2245204380a75c6bc6ac56f0000000040030901000000001100011000000000
hash2: 68a74f2a36c8906068c6cd6f00000000020000000000000080a7d06f00000000
```

I am aware the endianess in my program are not the same of the python result, but this I can fix later, when I get the correct result. Looking in the code below, can anyone give a hint of what I am missing here?

```
#define ROTLEFT(a,b) (((a) << (b)) | ((a) >> (32-(b))))
#define ROTRIGHT(a,b) (((a) >> (b)) | ((a) << (32-(b))))

#define CH(x,y,z) (((x) & (y)) ^ (~(x) & (z)))
#define MAJ(x,y,z) (((x) & (y)) ^ ((x) & (z)) ^ ((y) & (z)))

#define EP0(x) (ROTRIGHT(x,2) ^ ROTRIGHT(x,13) ^ ROTRIGHT(x,22))
#define EP1(x) (ROTRIGHT(x,6) ^ ROTRIGHT(x,11) ^ ROTRIGHT(x,25))

#define SIG0(x) (ROTRIGHT(x,7) ^ ROTRIGHT(x,18) ^ ((x) >> 3))
#define SIG1(x) (ROTRIGHT(x,17) ^ ROTRIGHT(x,19) ^ ((x) >> 10))

Sha256::Sha256(vector<BYTE> data) {
    SIZE64 L = data.size() / 2;
    SIZE64 K = 0;
    while( (L + 1 + K + 8) % 64 != 0)
        K = K + 1;

    for(int i=0; i<L; i++) {
        BYTE c = (data[i] % 32 + 9) % 25 * 16 + (data[i+1] % 32 + 9) % 25;
        source.push_back(c);
    }

    source.push_back(0x80);

    for(int i=0; i<K; i++)
        source.push_back(0x00);

    SIZE64 x = L + 1 + K + 8;
    for(int i=0; i<sizeof(x); i++)
        source.push_back( x >> i*8 );
}

Sha256::Sha256(array<BYTE, SHA256_BLOCK_SIZE> data) {
    SIZE64 L = data.size() / 2;
    SIZE64 K = 0;
    while( (L + 1 + K + 8) % 64 != 0)
        K = K + 1;

    for(int i=0; i<L; i++) {
        BYTE c = (data[i] % 32 + 9) % 25 * 16 + (data[i+1] % 32 + 9) % 25;
        source.push_back(c);
    }

    source.push_back(0x80);

    for(int i=0; i<K; i++)
        source.push_back(0x00);

    SIZE64 x = L + 1 + K + 8;
    for(int i=0; i<sizeof(x); i++)
        source.push_back( x >> i*8 );
}

array<BYTE, SHA256_BLOCK_SIZE> Sha256::hash() {
    array<BYTE, SHA256_BLOCK_SIZE> result;

    WORD32 h0 = 0x6a09e667, h1 = 0xbb67ae85, h2 = 0x3c6ef372, h3 = 0xa54ff53a, h4 = 0x510e527f, h5 = 0x9b05688c, h6 = 0x1f83d9ab, h7 = 0x5be0cd19;

    WORD32 k[64] = {0x428a2f98, 0x71374491, 0xb5c0fbcf, 0xe9b5dba5, 0x3956c25b, 0x59f111f1, 0x923f82a4, 0xab1c5ed5, 0xd807aa98, 0x12835b01, 0x243185be, 0x550c7dc3, 0x72be5d74, 0x80deb1fe, 0x9bdc06a7, 0xc19bf174, 0xe49b69c1, 0xefbe4786, 0x0fc19dc6, 0x240ca1cc, 0x2de92c6f, 0x4a7484aa, 0x5cb0a9dc, 0x76f988da, 0x983e5152, 0xa831c66d, 0xb00327c8, 0xbf597fc7, 0xc6e00bf3, 0xd5a79147, 0x06ca6351, 0x14292967, 0x27b70a85, 0x2e1b2138, 0x4d2c6dfc, 0x53380d13, 0x650a7354, 0x766a0abb, 0x81c2c92e, 0x92722c85, 0xa2bfe8a1, 0xa81a664b, 0xc24b8b70, 0xc76c51a3, 0xd192e819, 0xd6990624, 0xf40e3585, 0x106aa070, 0x19a4c116, 0x1e376c08, 0x2748774c, 0x34b0bcb5, 0x391c0cb3, 0x4ed8aa4a, 0x5b9cca4f, 0x682e6ff3, 0x748f82ee, 0x78a5636f, 0x84c87814, 0x8cc70208, 0x90befffa, 0xa4506ceb, 0xbef9a3f7, 0xc67178f2};

    WORD32 a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, t1, t2, m[64];

    for(int chunk=0; chunk<=source.size()/64; chunk++) {
        for (i = 0, j = chunk*64; i < 16; ++i, j += 4)
            m[i] = (source[j] << 24) | (source[j + 1] << 16) | (source[j + 2] << 8) | (source[j + 3]);
        for ( ; i < 64; ++i)
            m[i] = SIG1(m[i - 2]) + m[i - 7] + SIG0(m[i - 15]) + m[i - 16];

        a = h0;
        b = h1;
        c = h2;
        d = h3;
        e = h4;
        f = h5;
        g = h6;
        h = h7;

        for (i = 0; i < 64; ++i) {
            t1 = h + EP1(e) + CH(e,f,g) + k[i] + m[i];
            t2 = EP0(a) + MAJ(a,b,c);
            h = g;
            g = f;
            f = e;
            e = d + t1;
            d = c;
            c = b;
            b = a;
            a = t1 + t2;
        }

        h0 += a;
        h1 += b;
        h2 += c;
        h3 += d;
        h4 += e;
        h5 += f;
        h6 += g;
        h7 += h;
    }

    for(int i=0; i<4; i++) result[0] = h0 >> i;
    for(int i=0; i<4; i++) result[1] = h1 >> i;
    for(int i=0; i<4; i++) result[2] = h2 >> i;
    for(int i=0; i<4; i++) result[3] = h3 >> i;
    for(int i=0; i<4; i++) result[4] = h4 >> i;
    for(int i=0; i<4; i++) result[5] = h5 >> i;
    for(int i=0; i<4; i++) result[6] = h6 >> i;
    for(int i=0; i<4; i++) result[7] = h7 >> i;

  return result;
}
```

Comment: What's the purpose of `for(int i=0; i<4; i++) result[0] = h0 >> i;`?

Comment: Produce the final hash value? Which will be returned to the caller?

Comment: Why the shifts though? I don't see that in the algorithm. And why the loop? You're overwriting the result again with each loop; you've effectively written: `result[0] = h0; result[0] = h0 >> 1; result[0] = h0 >> 2; result[0] = h0 >> 3;` where each one overwrites the last, so this is equivalent to just doing `result[0] = h0 >> 3`. And I don't think you're meant to discard those three top bits are you?

Comment: Ok, I remember the reason for the loop: as `result` is an array, and `h0...h7` are of type WORD (unsigned int), which has 4 bytes, I move each byte from `h0...h7` into one element of the array.

Comment: BYTE (int the array definition) = unsigned char

Comment: Right, that makes more sense. In that case you'll need shifts of 24, 16 and 8 bits, not 1,2,3, and you'll need to increment the result index for each loop too: h0 should be entries 0-3 of result, h1 entries 4-7 etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the `Sha256::hash` function, `result` is a `BYTE` array, whereas `h0` is a `WORD32`. You might want to split `h0` into 4 `BYTE`s and store into the `result` array, but the for loop at the end of the function won't achieve your goal.

What you want to do is to concatenate `h0` to `h7`, and then extract the bytes from `h0` to `h7` by shifting 24, 16, 8, 0 bits:

```cpp
// concatenate h0 to h7
WORD32 hs[8] = {h0, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, h7};

// extract bytes from hs to result
for(int i=0; i<8; i++) { // loop from h0 to h7
    result[i*4  ] = hs[i] >> 24; // the most significant byte of h_i
    result[i*4+1] = hs[i] >> 16;
    result[i*4+2] = hs[i] >> 8;
    result[i*4+3] = hs[i];       // the least significant byte of h_i
}
```

#### EDIT

After some testing, I found another error:

```cpp
for(int chunk=0; chunk<=source.size()/64; chunk++) {
                      ^^
```

should be

```cpp
for(int chunk=0; chunk<source.size()/64; chunk++) {
                      ^
```

`chuck` starts from 0, so you should use `<` instead of `<=`.
For example, when `source.size()` is 64, you only have 1 chunk to process.

#### EDIT2

I fully tested your code and found two problems in the constructors of the `Sha256` class.

Your code implies that you assume the `vector<BYTE>` passed to the constructor is a **hex string**. That is OK, but you use the same code for the `array<BYTE, SHA256_BLOCK_SIZE>` version, which is the return type of `hash()` function, which returns a `BYTE` array instead of hex string.

For a `BYTE` array, you can simply push the byte `data[i]` into the `source`. Also, `L` should be `data.size()` because every element has size 1 in a byte array.

Besides, you try to append the size of the input(`x`) to `source`, but `x` should not include the appended one and zeros, and it is the **bit** count of the input, so `x` should simply be `L*8`. Also, the size should be a **big-endian integer**, so you have to push the bigger byte first:

```
for(int i=0; i<sizeof(x); i++) // WRONG: little endian
for(int i=sizeof(SIZE64)-1; i>=0; i--) // Correct: big endian
```

I have made it execute correctly and output:

```
hash1: b9d751533593ac10cdfb7b8e03cad8babc67d8eaeac0a3699b82857dacac9390
hash2: 1dbd981fe6985776b644b173a4d0385ddc1aa2a829688d1e0000000000000000
```

If you encounter other problems, feel free to ask. You are very close to the correct answer. Hope you can fix all the bugs successfully :)

#### EDIT3: implementation of other function

```cpp
struct BlockHeader {
    int version;
    string hashPrevBlock;
    string hashMerkleRoot;
    int time;
    int bits;
    int nonce;
    vector<BYTE> bytes();
};

#define c2x(x) (x>='A' && x<='F' ? (x-'A'+10) : x>='a' && x<='f' ? (x-'a'+10) : x-'0')
vector<BYTE> BlockHeader::bytes() {
    vector<BYTE> bytes;
    for (int i=24; i>=0; i-=8) bytes.push_back(version>>i);
    for (int i=0; i<hashPrevBlock.size(); i+=2)
        bytes.push_back(c2x(hashPrevBlock[i])<<4 | c2x(hashPrevBlock[i+1]));
    for (int i=0; i<hashMerkleRoot.size(); i+=2)
        bytes.push_back(c2x(hashMerkleRoot[i])<<4 | c2x(hashMerkleRoot[i+1]));
    for (int i=24; i>=0; i-=8) bytes.push_back(time>>i);
    for (int i=24; i>=0; i-=8) bytes.push_back(bits>>i);
    for (int i=24; i>=0; i-=8) bytes.push_back(nonce>>i);
    return bytes; // return bytes instead of hex string
}
```

```cpp
// exactly the same as the vector<BYTE> version
Sha256::Sha256(array<BYTE, SHA256_BLOCK_SIZE> data) {
    SIZE64 L = data.size(); // <<
    SIZE64 K = 0;
    while( (L + 1 + K + 8) % 64 != 0)
        K = K + 1;
    // can be simplified to: int K = (128-1-8-L%64)%64;

    // ** thanks to "chux - Reinstate Monica" pointing out i should be a SIZE64
    for(SIZE64 i=0; i<L; i++) { // **
        source.push_back(data[i]); // <<
    }

    source.push_back(0x80);

    for(int i=0; i<K; i++)
        source.push_back(0x00);

    SIZE64 x = L*8; // <<
    for(int i=sizeof(SIZE64)-1; i>=0; i--) { // big-endian
        source.push_back(x >> i*8);
    }
}
```

#### EDIT4: variable size in for loop

As "chux - Reinstate Monica" pointed out, it may be a problem if the size  of the data is bigger than `INT_MAX`. All for-loop using a size as the upper limit should use a `size_t` type counter(instead of `int`) to prevent this problem.

```cpp
// in BlockHeader::bytes()
for (size_t i=0; i<hashPrevBlock.size(); i+=2)
// in Sha256::hash()
for (size_t chunk=0; chunk<source.size()/64; chunk++)
// in main()
for (size_t i=0; i<h1.size(); i++)
for (size_t i=0; i<h2.size(); i++)
```

Notice that `size_t` is `unsigned`. The reverse version won't work because `i` is never less than 0.

```cpp
for (size_t i=data.size()-1; i>=0; i--) // infinite loop
```

Comment: the part about `x` is done in both constructors? I just made this changes you suggested, but still getting different results.

Comment: I also tried a version with only 1 constructor: https://pastebin.com/ihHd8dvD /  https://pastebin.com/0F8jQ6Sz

Comment: I am thinking my problem could be when I try convert the class `BlockHeader` to a string. How you do it in your test? Do you use a `struct` or have a method returning a `vector` with the class data? code: https://pastebin.com/0gHyANi2

Comment: I have edited my answer to provide the implementation of other function. Yes, I used `struct` to simplify the test. And I convert the `BlockHeader` into a byte array instead of a string. (See my edited answer)

Comment: Why continue using `SIZE64`, `BYTE` vs standard `uint64_t, uint8_t`, etc?

Comment: `for(int i=0; i<data.size(); i++)` is a problem when `data.size() > INT_MAX`.

Comment: Thank you to point out the potential issue. I edited my answer to fix that. As for `SIZE64` and `BYTE`, I use the same notation as the original code. It might be better to use `uint64_t` and `uint8_t` instead. Thank you for your suggestion!

Comment: After changes based on the updates 3 and 4, now the program seems to get stuck on a infinite loop somewhere; i cannot figure out where. try the old `BlockHeader:bytes` method and the new; do not looks like the issue is here. code: https://pastebin.com/0gHyANi2 https://pastebin.com/ihHd8dvD https://pastebin.com/0F8jQ6Sz

Comment: Also, is it possible keep using only one constructor in the Sha256 class? I think this way could be more simple.

Comment: You may try to log something in main function(or other function) to figure out where does it get stuck. For example, add something like `puts("FLAG1");` before `Sha256 hash1(header.bytes());` and add `puts("FLAG2");` after it. If `FLAG1` is printed but `FLAG2` is not, then there might be some problems in `Sha256 hash1(header.bytes());` .

Comment: the issue is here: `for(size_t i=sizeof(x)-1; i>=0; i--)`: after i==0, the loop keeps going.

Comment: Because `size_t` is `unsigned`, it is always `>=0`. You should use `int` instead. (`sizeof(x)` is a small constant, so there won't be any problem to use int) Sorry for confusing you with EDIT4.

Comment: yes, i just change back the loop to `for(int i=sizeof(x)-1; i>=0; i--)` and now works. but still cannot get the right result for the hash.

Comment: Have you updated the constructor of `Sha256` to EDIT3? I'm not sure what does your code look like now.

Comment: the code looks like this right now: https://pastebin.com/ihHd8dvD https://pastebin.com/0F8jQ6Sz https://pastebin.com/0gHyANi2

Comment: If you use my version of `BlockHeader::bytes`, you have to change both constructors of `Sha256` to EDIT3, because the code now you're using assumes the input is a **hex string**, whereas my version of `BlockHeader::bytes` outputs a **byte array**.

Comment: Seems like it is working now, but the hash is being display as `hash2: 1dbd981fe6985776b644b173a4d0385ddc1aa2a829688d1e0000000000000000`. each pair looks like are being displayed incorrectly? Like, they are inverted? I mean, the expected result (with a different endianess) is `00000000000000001e8d6829a8a21adc5d38d0a473b144b6765798e61f98bd1d`.

Comment: The endian is correct, you just need to reverse the output bytes.

Comment: yes, it's almost that. I change the loop in the `main` to: `for(int i=h1.size(); i>=0; i--)` and `for(int i=h2.size(); i>=0; i--)` and now the second hash is display with a 2 instead of 0 in the first character: `hash2: 2000000000000000001e8d6829a8a21adc5d38d0a473b144b6765798e61f98bd1d`

Comment: The last index is `.size()-1` instead of `.size()`.